# Imagem não carrega em HTML

Tags: html, imagem

```
<html>

<head>
<title>equipe setembro</title>
</head>

<body>
<b><p align=center><font face="verdana" size="7" color="#1C1C1C">Equipe Setembro</font></p>
<br>
<p align=center><font face="verdana" size=5 color="#FFD700"> Faça parte agora</font></p>
<p><img scr="C:\Users\anrocha\Desktop\setembroexperimente.png" width="800" height="600"></p>

</html>
```

Gostaria de saber porque não carrega a imagem no código acima, iniciei o passo a passo corretamente, mas como sou iniciante no curso de HTML não estou conseguindo localizar o erro.

Comment: Que curso é esse que ensina a escrever HTML como em 1993?! Esse tipo de código, com align=center, <font> etc já não se usa mais há MUITO tempo. O problema pode ser o caminho da sua imagem, utilize um servidor web (local, pesquise por xampp), e sirva a imagem com o protocolo HTTP como se deve fazer na web.

Comment: Dentro da tag `<img>`, a propriedade `src` está como `scr`. Veja [mais](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)

Comment: kkkk curso gratuito na fundação bradesco

Comment: Alessandro, não sei qual é o seu objetivo com esse curso. Mas sugiro que escolha um curso mais atualizado. Caso não queira gastar, tem vários cursos muito bons e gratuitos no site [Curso em Vídeo](https://www.cursoemvideo.com/cursos/)

Comment: Sim Carlos, obrigado pela sugestão. Eu realmente não sabia que o curso estava ultrapassado, estou bem no inicio do curso de ads, conhecendo as linguagens e tudo. E sempre fiz cursos na fundação Bradesco, em outras áreas.  Mas já estou estudando algoritmos com o prof. Guanabara e vou ver tbm HTML e CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Tente não usar caminhos absolutos por exemplo: "C:\Users\anrocha\Desktop\setembroexperimente.png"
Use caminhos relativos dentro da pasta de seu projeto.

E no seu caso na tag img a propriedade é src, você escreveu scr :)

```html
<img src="C:\Users\anrocha\Desktop\setembroexperimente.png" width="800" height="600">
```

Deixei um exemplo para você baixar e verificar:
https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-cartwright-fitm9

Espero ter ajudado, grande abraço

Comment: Eu passei uma hora olhando pro código sem enxergar isso kkkk muito obrigado, agora deu certo !!